# How can I open the command line in Firefox Quantum?

Tags: firefox

There’s a command line built into Firefox, which allows various options such as taking screenshots and restarting the browser. It used to open with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, but since the upgrade to Firefox 57, that no longer does anything.

I have seen the command line since the upgrade (it was open in one Firefox window, and remained open after the upgrade), so I know that it does still exist in Firefox Quantum. However, I have since closed that window, and cannot get it back. Is there now a different keyboard shortcut to reveal the command line?

The [Mozilla documentation for the command line](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options) still says <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.

I am using Firefox Quantum 57.0 on Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: Just tested in a VM with a fresh installed firefox 57 it is still shift+f2. maybe backup your bookmarks and so on and start a fresh profile?

Comment: Hmm. I'll try it.

Comment: Can someone add a screenshot so I know how it's supposed to look like!

Comment: @George Does this help?  https://i.imgur.com/yFuJOJH.png

Comment: Thanks @terrance that's what I got on my try but thought it was wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Graphical Command Line Interface (GCLI) has now been removed from Firefox. Much of its functionality is now in the Web Developer Console.

There are two ways to access the Web Developer Console:

- Tools → Web Developer → Web Console
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

As far I could see while testing, this is still on <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.

I suggest backing up your bookmarks and so on (Firefox-Sync) and start over on a fresh profile.

This you can do easily by closing Firefox and deleting `~/.mozilla` and `~/.cache/mozilla` via terminal:

```
rm -r ~/.mozilla ~/.cache/mozilla
```

or you can start up Firefox with the profile manager via terminal by:

```
firefox -P
```

Comment: It's actually working inconsistently for me. Sometimes it opens; sometimes nothing happens.